# Malware by wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, malware

If a portable windows program has malware and I open it by wine, just close it to do away with the malware?
Sorry for my grammar. I'm not fluent in English

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A windows program with a virus attached will remain dormant on your Ubuntu system. If you then open the windows program in wine, and execute it, it shouldn't harm Ubuntu. Do not open wine from terminal with sudo wine, because that gives wine explicit rights on your system.

You could try clamav to  scan windows files before use also.